# Glide doesn't resize the image when the thumbnail(...) method is used

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-glide

Using the `thumbnail(0.5f)` should reduce the size of the image to 50% its original but it doesn't.

Consider the following code.

```
Glide.with(context).load(imgUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)   //Make this work.
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```

I have tried removing the other methods like `crossFade()`, `diskCacheStrategy()` etc. to see if they were creating some problem, but no it still doesn't resize the image.

I have also tried to load the view dynamically through code instead of using an xml file, it still doesn't resize.

Full disclosure, i am doing all of this inside a fragment.

I don't know what it is i am doing that is wrong. Hope someone helps.

Comment: Can you just try `.skipMemoryCache(true)` and try removing all other methods like you said in the question. May be the wrong sized image is cached in memory.

Comment: @sunil tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `override(int,int)` method for resize image dynamically. glide generates a new bitmap with width and height mentioned in override(w,h) and then load the image into `ImageView`. You can use `fitCenter()` to align the image. You can also use `diskCacheStrategy()`.

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(imgUrl)
            .override(800, 400)
            .fitCenter()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageView)
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Ty i will definitely try that out, but what if i don't know the original width and height of the image. Using thumbnail removed the condition for knowing the original dimensions. It just reduced the size by whatever floating number between 0 and 1 we passed to it. What if i want to resize the image depending on the original size of the image?

Comment: What if i want to resize the image depending on the original size of the image?-- this will create heap memory because don't know the actual size of image from the url, also it will be slow to load, so best way to set dimension to imageview according to we want.

Comment: @Srushti The wording of my reply may have created this misunderstanding. I understand using override(,) doesn't require prior knowledge of the image. I was just pointing out that with thumbnail you could resize the image in relation to the original image i.e. half the original size, quarter the original size etc. but with override(,) you just provide the width and height you want but it's not mathematically bound to the original size. And as hemant said it may load slower compared to override(,) but idk why it feels "cleaner" to me. lol

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code for the Glide module is correct, But there might be a error with "context", Check weather the context is null. Or if not try to use getContext() method inside the fragment as follow.

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(imgUrl)
            .thumbnail(0.5f) 
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageView);
```

for more reference try [Glide](https://www.schrodinger.com/glide) documentation.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Still looking for the solution?